# Is there a way to use backspace in terminal without hitting backspace key

Tags: c++, json, bash, visual-studio-code

I have a configuration in VS code for running CPP files using code runner extension. It is configured to run "cd $dir" which outputs

> cd "c\Users\user\folder\"

instead of

> cd "c\Users\user\folder"

Because of the last backslash, this command not giving any output so I am looking for  an option to use a backslash to add after this command or is there any way to change the value of $dir in json itself.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `cd "c:\Users\user\folder\"` or `cd "c:\Users\user\folder"` without the colon you have a relative path that attempts to access  `c` folder that is in the current working directory.

Comment: Does it work to add a backspace to your shell command, as in `cd $dir\u007f`?

Comment: Thanks, @Mark. It worked. Can you answer below so I can accept your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest adding a shell delete to your command: `\u007f` so

`cd $dir\u007f` should delete the last character output by `$dir`.

The hexcode is here: https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/blob/0e45909c7e79c83452493d2cd46d99c0a0bb585f/src/common/data/EscapeSequences.ts but it is easy to convert to unicode.